# Using the Spherical mean, show that $V(x)=\frac{|y^2|-|x|^2}{|y-x|^N}$ is hamonic over $R^N\setminus\{y\}$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

> Let $y\in R^N$. Show that $V(x)=\frac{|y^2|-|x|^2}{|y-x|^N}$ is hamonic over $R^N\setminus\{y\}$.

This is an exercise of my first course in  PDE.

**My doubt**

I know that the Laplace's equation is: 
$$
\Delta u=\sum_{j=1}^N \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x_i^2}
$$

In other hand I have that

$$
V(x)=\frac{|y^2|-|x|^2}{|y-x|^N}
$$

When I have to calculate the derivative of $V(x)$ this is becoming a monster! I believe that exists other way to verify using spherical mean but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You want to show that $V(x)$ satisfies laplaces equation on $\mathbb{R}^N\setminus\{y\}$.

That would make it harmonic.

**OR**, you need to show that the mean integral of $V$ over a sphere boundary of a sphere in $\mathbb{R}^N$, centred at $x_0$ is equivalent to $V(x_0)$.

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}V(x)=\large\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(\frac{|y^2|-(x_1^2+...+x_N^2)}{(y_1-x_1)^2+...+(y_N-x_N)^2})$

$=\frac{(-2x_i)((y_1-x_1)^2+...+(y_N-x_N)^2)+2(y_i-x_i)(|y^2|-(x_1^2+...+x_N^2))}{((y_1-x_1)^2+...+(y_N-x_N)^2)^2}$

Can you do the next differentiation step? since it looks like things will cancel nicely when you take the sum of all of the second derivatives.

Comment: Ok, but my doubt is how to calculate the derivative or the integral of $V(x)$... I'm confuse with this.

Comment: I've put in an edit for the first derivative, hope it helps!

Comment: I missed out the $N$-th power in the denominator, my bad!

Comment: This is wrong?

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}V(x)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left( \frac{|y^2|-(x_1^2+...+x_N^2)}{[(y_1-x_2)^2+...+(y_N-x_N)^2]^{\frac{N}{2}}} \right)=
$$

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}V(x)=\left\{ -2x_i[(y_1-x_1)^2+...+(y_N-x_N)^2]^{\frac{N}{2}}+[|y^2|-(x_1^2+...+x_N^2)]\frac{N}{2}[(y_1-x_1)^2+...+(y_N-x_N)^2]^{\frac{N-2}{2}}(2)(-1) \right\}\frac{1}{|y-x|^{2N}}
$$

$$
=\frac{-2x_i(|y-x|^N)-N(y-x|)^{N-2}}{|y-x|^{2N}}
$$

Comment: This is becoming a monster!!